# Copy assets files in system android 4.4.2

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I've always use this method (obviously with root and mounting system as RW) to copy assets in /system/etc/init.d folder in android 4.1.2 but since I've switched to kitkat this method doesn't work anymore. SELinux is disabled, and I don't have External SD card write bug.
I have made some logcats in my device and I don't get any errors, the app takes correctly SU permissions, mounts system as RW but it doesn't copy files.

```
// File name, path , file permission, context.
public static void copyAssets(String script,String path,int mode,Context context) {
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = assetManager.open(script);
        File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), script);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        copyFile(in, out);
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.e("cocoremanager", "Failed to handle: " + script, e);
    }
}
```

When I call it:

```
Utils.copyAssets("asset_name", "/system/etc/init.d", 777, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

SOLVED: just forgot to add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission into manifest.

Comment: Have you put `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your manifest?

Comment: Oh you have illuminated me, I have forgotten to add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission into manifest. Thank you man now it is workin' like a charm.